# modify router meta field in Vue.js project using Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, gridsome

I'm trying to specify a [meta object](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) for a route auto-generated for me by Gridsome, like this:

```
meta: {
      auth: true
    }
```

But there isn't a normal routes/index.js file in Gridsome - only a router object exposed like this in index.js:

```
export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) 
{}
```

How do I reach into the router and add the meta to the specific routes I want to modify?

Comment: any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `route` object via `this` inside components script tag

```
<script>
export default {
  created () {
    this.$route.meta = {requiresAuth: true}    
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I dont think thats working "Cannot assign to read only property 'meta' of object '#<Object>'"